# Antd Input value set using ref is getting cleared after state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, use-ref

I set Antd Input value using ref and it is getting automatically cleared after state update. How to fix it ? This is the
[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-elion-rv576l?file=/src/App.js) to reproduce the issue.

I'm setting input value for native html input using ref and it persists between state updates.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score -1):

you should use to useState
It will look like this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-grass-mxj8m8)
hope this helps you

Comment: Yeah, useState will help but I don't want to rerender. That's the reason I'm using ref in the first place